# Why does score evaluate score +1 when str is set to opt2 and opt3

Tags: javascript

I have a function which calculates the score in a survey depending on the chosen option but I am always getting the same value which is in the first `if` condition and I guess that the answer variable is the problem because it shows nothing.

```
var questions = [
    {
        "question": "L'impact est ",
        "option1": "faible",
        "option2": "moyen",
        "option3": "haut",
    },
    {
       "question": "L'impact2 est ",
       "option1": "faible",
       "option2": "moyen",
       "option3": "haut",
    },
]

var currentQuestion = 0;
var score1 = 0;
var totQuestions = questions.length;
var number = 0;

var progressText = document.getElementById("progressText");
var container = document.getElementById('quizContainer');
var questionEl = document.getElementById('question');
var opt1 = document.getElementById('opt1');
var opt2 = document.getElementById('opt2');
var opt3 = document.getElementById('opt3');
var nextButton = document.getElementById('nextButton');
var resultCont = document.getElementById('result');
var chartBar = document.getElementById('bar-horzontal');

function loadQuestion(questionIndex) {
    var q = questions[questionIndex];
    questionEl.textContent = (questionIndex + 1) + '. ' + q.question;
    opt1.textContent = q.option1;
    opt2.textContent = q.option2;
    opt3.textContent = q.option3;
    progressText.innerText = questionIndex + 1 + ' de ' + totQuestions + ' 
questions ';
};

function loadNextQuestion() {
    var selectedOption = 
 document.querySelector('input[type=radio]:checked');
     if (!selectedOption) {
         alert('veuillez sélectionner votre réponse');
         return;
     }

     var answer =selectedOption.Value;      
     if (questions[currentQuestion].opt1 == answer) {
         score1 += 1;
     } else if (questions[currentQuestion].opt2 == answer) {
         score1 += 2;
     } else {
         score1 += 3
     }

     selectedOption.checked = false;
     currentQuestion++;
     progressText.textContent = questionEl / totQuestions

     if (currentQuestion == totQuestions - 1) {
        nextButton.textContent = 'Finish';
     }
     if (currentQuestion == totQuestions) {
         container.style.display = 'none';
         resultCont.style.display = '';
         resultCont.textContent = 'le résultat est ' + ' ' + score1 + ' ' 
 +answer+' ' ;
        return;
     }
     loadQuestion(currentQuestion);
 };
 loadQuestion(currentQuestion);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In HTML, `input` elements don't have property `textContent` so you shouldn't add text inside `radio` element, you can use `span` or `label`.

Also `q.opt1` is `undefined`.

```js
var questions = [{
    "question": "L'impact est",
    "option1": "faible",
    "option2": "moyen",
    "option3": "haut"
  },
  {
    "question": "L'impact est",
    "option1": "faible",
    "option2": "moyen",
    "option3": "haut"
  }
]

var currentQuestion = 0;
var score1 = 0;
var totQuestions = questions.length;
var number = 0;

var progressText = document.getElementById("progressText");
var container = document.getElementById('quizContainer');
var questionEl = document.getElementById('question');
var opt1 = document.getElementById('opt1');
var opt2 = document.getElementById('opt2');
var opt3 = document.getElementById('opt3');
var lbl_1 = document.getElementById('lbl_1');
var lbl_2 = document.getElementById('lbl_2');
var lbl_3 = document.getElementById('lbl_3');
var nextButton = document.getElementById('nextButton');
var resultCont = document.getElementById('result');
var chartBar = document.getElementById('bar-horzontal');

function loadQuestion(questionIndex) {
  var q = questions[questionIndex];
  questionEl.textContent = (questionIndex + 1) + '. ' + q.question;
  opt1.value = lbl_1.textContent = q.option1;
  opt2.value = lbl_2.textContent = q.option2;
  opt3.value = lbl_3.textContent = q.option3;
  progressText.innerText = questionIndex + 1 + ' de ' + totQuestions + ' questions ';
};

function loadNextQuestion() {
  var selectedOption = document.querySelector('input[type=radio]:checked');
  if (!selectedOption) {
    alert('veuillez sélectionner votre réponse');
    return;
  }

  var answer = selectedOption.value;
  if (questions[currentQuestion].option1 == answer) {
    score1 += 1;
  } else if (questions[currentQuestion].option2 == answer) {
    score1 += 2;
  } else {
    score1 += 3
  }

  selectedOption.checked = false;
  currentQuestion++;
  progressText.textContent = "Answered: "+(currentQuestion / totQuestions) * 100 + "%";

  if (currentQuestion == totQuestions - 1) {
    nextButton.textContent = 'Finish';
  }
  if (currentQuestion == totQuestions) {
    nextButton.style.display = 'none';
    container.style.display = 'none';
    resultCont.style.display = '';
    resultCont.textContent = 'le résultat est ' + ' ' + score1 + ' ';
    return;
  }
  loadQuestion(currentQuestion);
};
loadQuestion(currentQuestion);
```

```html
<div id="quizContainer">
  <p id="question"></p>
  <input id="opt1" name="option" type="radio"><label for="opt1" id="lbl_1"></label>
  <input id="opt2" name="option" type="radio" /><label for="opt2" id="lbl_2"></label>
  <input id="opt3" name="option" type="radio" /><label for="opt3" id="lbl_3"></label>
</div>
<br/>
<button id="nextButton" onclick="loadNextQuestion()">Next</button>
<br/>
<p id="progressText"></p>
<div id="bar-horzontal"></div>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are telling the program to add extra point to option 2 and 3. Look at the code below you are saying to add 2 point if its option 2 and and 3 points if its option 3.

```
} else if (questions[currentQuestion].opt2 == answer) {
   score1 += 2;
} else {
   score1 += 3
```

I think they should be like this.

```
} else if (questions[currentQuestion].opt2 == answer) {
   score1 += 1;
} else {
   score1 += 1
```

Comment: i can't understand you can you clarify please

Comment: @mariem how about now.

Comment: i actually want the function to add 1 point if the user's answer was the first option 2 point if it was the secom and 3 if it was the third

Comment: @mariem then what do you mean by score evaluate +1

Comment: it means if i choose option 1 or option2 or option3 score variable is always incremented by 1 only

Comment: @mariem can you put the html as well